# css fixed randomly with JS and more than one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to know if there is any way I can change a `div`, everytime I use it.

I want to change in a `div` the top and the left position on the page, but not only in one div, in many divs, and not realoading the page.

E.g

```
.class{
  background-color:black;
  color: white;
  position:absolute;
  top: RANDOM;
  left: RANDOM;
}

<div1 class="class"></div> /// this would be positioned top:100px and left 200px
<div2 class="class"></div> /// this would be positioned top:245px and left 298px
<div3 class="class"></div> /// this would be positioned top:190px and left 490px
<div4 class="class"></div> /// this would be positioned top: 89px and left 344px
```

All this in the same page, is this possible?
I tried to find something like that, but I only found a scrip that would change a div ID whenever I click on it, not too many divs in the same page.

Comment: what do you mean?? random top, and left on div??

Comment: is there any relation to get the top and left dimension?? or u just want it by manually calculation??

Comment: perhaps the following answer is you might be looking for

Comment: and what means by `div1`, `div2` etc  ??no valid tag

Comment: @diEcho perhaps he meant to comment it

Comment: @diEcho @ExperimentX I was just trying to explain that they were different divs lol, i want it to randomly and automatic give me different values of top and left for each div i use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery, to the rescue:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
  $(this).css('top', Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
  $(this).css('left', Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
});
```

And (overkill, I know), a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pZ7Kf/10/.

Comment: thank you so much!, that's exacly what i wanted!, is not working for me yet, but i'll take it from here, thank you again!

Comment: No problem. Just Google how to generate random integers with JavaScript, as it's a bit unintuitive.